# Make image display as a circle

Tags: css, image, image-processing, geometry

I found a way to do this with CSS3, but IE still doesn't support it. I wish to know if there is a way to do it so that it may be compatible with all of the popular browsers.
I understand I can do it with a mask, but if I want to display a user-uploaded image in the background this is not an option or at least I don't know how to achieve that. Can anyone give me an idea about it? Maybe an image processing in the background when the image is uploaded to turn it into circle and make a transparent background, but I don't know how to process that?

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for why a mask doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSS3 `border-radius`, but as you mentioned, old IE does not support this property.

But [PIE.htc](http://css3pie.com/) (PIE.js in my example) can pollyfill this in-

hence- http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/IBrow.

This uses standard `border-radius`, and a copy-and-pasted pie.js,
The border radius is 50% of the height and the width of the image.

I can't speak for performance (see the docs), but I think this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay a PNG image that has a transparent circle in the middle of a square with the background color you need. Then position this over the uploaded image to give it the illusion of being a circle.